# user input file not reading into array c++

Tags: c++

This program is supposed to ask the user for their filename and then read the data from the file into an

Comment: What about the code doesn't work?

Comment: I think i'm getting the memory allocation when I run the program instead of the contents on the file? I'm having problems retrieving the user's file...

Comment: What is the actual filename?

Comment: You never verify that you actually succeeded in opening the file. This leads to your array containing indeterminate values. If you initialise the array with `int num[SIZE] = {0};` you'll see a bunch of zeros.

Comment: for example the user enters a file named "numbers" which is a .txt file and already exists beforehand, but I just wrote the code to verify if the file successfully opens and it does not

Comment: How would I successfully open the user's file and store the contents into an array?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you fail on the user input.
You have to input the whole Path if you do it the way this code works and i guess you just type the executable.
A path would look like this

```
"C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\Programme\\bla.exe"
```

You should check if the the try to open the file successes.

Comment: program may also accept relative paths, if underlying filesystem supports it(windows, linux and OS X should all support relative paths)

Comment: I don't understand.. how would I get that path from what the user enters? Would I have to enter that into the inputFile.open braces?Please clarify